# ValueError: hist method requires numerical columns, nothing to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I was going through a tutorial, but as I was running the code in an IDE, an error occurred. The link to the tutorial is here: https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2020/12/29/house-price-prediction-with-python/. This is the code I have so far:
First cell:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv"
names = ['longitude','latitude','housing_median_age','total_rooms','total_bedrooms',         'population','households','median_income','median_house_value','ocean_proximity']
housing = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)
housing.head()
```

Second cell:

```
housing.info()
```

Third cell:

```
housing.ocean_proximity.value_counts()
```

Fourth cell:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
housing.hist(bins=50,figsize=(10, 8))
plt.show()
```

It's in the second line of the fourth cell that I have an error. As the title states, the compiler says `ValueError: hist method requires numerical columns, nothing to plot.` Why is this?

Comment: When you use `pd.read_csv` that way there's no information regarding the data types in the DataFrame. You would need to use the `dtype` keyword argument and specify the data types manually.

Comment: Alright thanks. I was trying something like `housing = pd.read_csv(url, names=names, dtype={'longitude':float})`. It's still saying there's an error (it says `could not convert string to float: 'longitude'`). I don't think I need this explained, but how would I not include the title and only the numbers underneath it?

Comment: Use the `header` keyword argument. I believe `header=0` to indicate the first line is the column headings.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data type in your dataframe is not numeric, you can use info() to view the data type. If the data type is "object", you cannot draw a picture. You can try to convert the data into "float" or "int" and then use hist()